# Error while executing Python code JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 81870 (char 81869)

Tags: python-3.x, nested, ordereddictionary

I have a file which contains multiple nested list of dictionaries and with help of this channel, I have got the solution but when I tried to execute the below code getting an error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 81870 (char 81869)" and I tried to change the lines but still I get the same issue.

Here is the attached code with image format which I am trying to execute

```
import csv
import json
from pathlib import Path

 path = Path(r"")
 keys = "uid", "enabled", "login", "name"
 with open(path / "result.csv", "w", newline="") as out_f:
   writer = csv.DictWriter(out_f, fieldnames=keys, extrasaction='ignore')
   writer.writeheader()
for file in path.glob("*.iris"):
    with open(file) as inp_f:
        data = json.load(inp_f)
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Below is the sample file

```
{"streamType":"user",
"uid":17182,
"enabled":true,
"login":"xyz",
"name":"abcdef",
"comment":"",
"authSms":"",
"email":"",
"phone":"",
"location":"",
"extraLdapOu":"",
"mand":997,
"global":{
"userAccount":"View",
"uid":"",
"retention":"No",
"enabled":"",
"messages":"Change"},
"grants":[{"mand":997,"role":1051,"passOnToSubMand":true}],
```

And as per the above code , trying to fetch only required key/pairs or else is there any way to split the dictionaries with required key/pairs and process or is there any way to fetch only the required key/pairs

```
"streamType":"user",
"uid":17182,
"enabled":true,
"login":"xyz",
"name":"abcdef"
```

even though it will be there in other nested list of dictionaries?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, use the [edit] link in your question.

Comment: Please suggest from my above ask